# If the shoe fits, wear it

Tags: переклад

На сайті [The Phrase finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-shoe-fits.html): вислів ***If the shoe fits, wear it*** є ідіомою, яка використовується в мові для характеристики того, хто сприймає зауваження на свій рахунок.

Словопедія подає: **на злодієві (на злодії) шапка горить** як переклад з російської **на воре шапка горит**.

Чи є в українській мові власний сталий вислів, а не калька з російської, який можна було б використати в перекладі з англійської?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> На воре шапка горит.
>   [На] злодієві шапка горить. Пр. У злодія шапка горить. Пр. **Хто порося вкрав, у того в вухах пищить (квичить).** Пр.

[Джерело](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/search.php?fullname=%E2%EE%F0&submit=%D8%F3%EA%E0%F2%E8).

До того ж, я не думаю, що це калька з російської. Вона є в Номиса:

> «На злодію шапка горить!» — А він собі хвать за голову. Ном. № 11097.

[Джерело](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Ви подивіться за посиланням, там у давніх словниках є це прислів'я як приклад, зокрема в Уманця-Спілки:

> На злодїю шапка горить. н. пр.